# Exact specific parts of ADOConnection String

Tags: delphi, adoconnection

I have an ADO Connection String:

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=MYCOMPUTER\SQL2008;User ID=GuestUser;Password=password;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=DefaultDatabase;
```

And I want to read specific parts of the string into various `TEdit` controls. Is there a function that is able to parse that information for me or am I going to need to split strings at the semicolons, then again by the equal signs and read the first index of that string array?

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to parse the string as it is you can use a StringList setting `Delimiter` and `StrictDelimiter` and assign `DelimitedText`. You may then use Names and Values of the StringList.

```
var
  i:Integer;
  sl:TStringList;
begin
   sl:=TStringList.Create;
   try
     sl.Delimiter :=';';
     sl.StrictDelimiter := true;
     sl.DelimitedText := Con.ConnectionString;
     Memo1.Lines.Assign(sl);
   finally
     sl.Free;
   end;
end;
```

Access e.g. via `sl.Names[i]; sl.Values['Password']; sl.ValueFromIndex[i]`

Ado itself allows access through `Properties` which will list more than the assigned values and would be the preferable way.

```
var
 i:Integer;
begin
  For i := 0 to Con.Properties.Count - 1 do
      begin
        Memo1.Lines.Add(Con.Properties[i].Name + '='+ VarToStr(Con.Properties[i].Value));
      end;
end;
```

Comment: This way, or more precise but little more complicated would be to query e.g. the `IDBProperties` on an uninitialized dataset. [+1]